# Equivalent do Dash in gnome-classic?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-classic (no effects) instead of Unity. But I admit that the Dash launcher is useful sometimes. Is there an equivalent launcher that we could use with gnome-classic?

Comment: hi thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Tks!